# Why is reported AIC for OLS different for spatial lag vs spatial durbin models? (estimated in R)

Tags: r, autocorrelation, aic, spatial

I am working on a project that involves comparing spatial autocorrelation models. Why does the AIC reported for the base OLS model, titled "AIC for lm" in the output, differ between spatial lag and spatial durbin models? I estimate both the spaital lag and durbin models using the same command, lagsarlm(), included in the spdep package in R (I am using version 3.3.0). An example of the specific commands and output is included below.

In part, I want to calculate change in AIC for each model compared to the base OLS model (with no modeling of spatial autocorrelation processes). When I estimate the base OLS model using lm() in R, the AIC matches that of the "AIC for lm" reported for the spatial lag model (for the example below, AIC = 20527). When I estimate spatial error models (using errorsarlm() in spdep) the "AIC for lm" again matches the base OLS model that I estimate using lm() and the "AIC for lm" reported in the spatial lag model output. But the "AIC for lm" in the output for the spatial durbin model always differs in my data (in the example below, the "AIC for lm" is 20400).

When doing some online searching for information on estimating these models in R, I have noticed that this is consistent with other examples posted online--the "AIC for lm" differs slightly between spatial lag and spatial durbin models (which makes me suspect that this is not unique to the data I am working with).

Any insight on this difference would be greatly appreciated!

R examples:

Spatial Lag Model:

```
Call:lagsarlm(formula = m, listw = wall10, type = "lag")

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-2.95531 -0.82975 -0.35403  0.69569  4.54005 

Type: lag 
Coefficients: [omitted for space]

Rho: 0.28817, LR test value: 163.76, p-value: < 2.22e-16
Asymptotic standard error: 0.022108
    z-value: 13.034, p-value: < 2.22e-16
Wald statistic: 169.9, p-value: < 2.22e-16

Log likelihood: -10169.74 for lag model
ML residual variance (sigma squared): 1.3365, (sigma: 1.1561)
Number of observations: 6487 
Number of parameters estimated: 13 
AIC: 20365, (**AIC for lm: 20527**)
LM test for residual autocorrelation
test value: 24.277, p-value: 8.3411e-07
```

Spatial Durbin model:

```
Call:lagsarlm(formula = m, listw = wall10, type = "mixed")

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-2.54775 -0.81564 -0.33895  0.67464  4.53801 

Type: mixed 
Coefficients: [omitted for space]

Rho: 0.24164, LR test value: 95.769, p-value: < 2.22e-16
Asymptotic standard error: 0.024574
    z-value: 9.833, p-value: < 2.22e-16
Wald statistic: 96.688, p-value: < 2.22e-16

Log likelihood: -10129.89 for mixed model
ML residual variance (sigma squared): 1.3233, (sigma: 1.1504)
Number of observations: 6487 
Number of parameters estimated: 23 
AIC: 20306, (**AIC for lm: 20400**)
LM test for residual autocorrelation
test value: 22.986, p-value: 1.6319e-06
```

Comment: Out of interest, what is your formula for `m`? From my limited knowledge, with the spatial lag model you only include a spatial lag of the outcome variable, whereas the Durbin model includes spatial lags on the explanatory variables as well. See [here](http://www.people.fas.harvard.edu/~zhukov/Spatial6.pdf). Could that potentially explain the difference?

Comment: Yes, that is the difference in the estimation of the models and, therefore, the AICs for the models themselves. But my question concerns the "AIC for lm", which (I think) reports the AIC for the base OLS model for comparison purposes. When I estimate an OLS model using lm() in R for the outcome and set of covariates, the AIC reported is the same as that of the "AIC for lm" for the spatial lag model. My question is: why is the "AIC for lm" not also 20527 for the spatial durbin model?

Comment: Misunderstood your question; I see what you mean now.